# Book about the sun or stars in general

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, stars, stellar-physics

I would be interested to know if there are any popular science books on what we know about the physics and processes in our sun.

It may possibly be a book about stars in general, but since in recent years we have been able to observe our sun with a plethora of new instruments, I would be interested to hear whether past and recent findings have been consolidated into a book for which you do not need a physics degree to plough through it.

Comment: -1. No effort. Have you tried an internet search using your title, with the addition of "popular science"?

Comment: Sure I searched and found "Our Explosive Sun", but with very few reviews etc. do you want me  to put it in as an example in the question, because I didn't see that style in the other questions tagged "resource recommendations"

Comment: You could explain why this did not suit your needs. Amazon has 3 reviews - you are unlikely to get more here - and you can "look inside" to check the style and content for yourself. Googling your exact title gives *An Introduction to the Sun and Stars* by Green and Jones (4 reviews on Amazon). With the addition of "popular science" you get *Nearsest Star* by Leon Golub (7 reviews on Amazon). ... All questions are expected to show effort. Showing what you tried and why it didn't work for you saves us a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a thousand books about the basic fusion processes going on in the Sun, but if you're interested in something a bit different I strongly recommend [The Music of the Sun by William J.Chaplin](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/cka/Music-Sun-Story-Helioseismology-William-J-Chaplin/1851684514).

The Sun, like any coherent object, has oscillatory modes and this book is about how those modes were discovered and what their study can reveal about the structure of the Sun. It is written for the popular market and requires minimal knowledge of science to enjoy, though some knowledge of the Sun and a basic grasp of maths will increase your enjoyment.